# How can I customize exception mappings of default AuthenticationEventPublisher in Grails Spring Security Plugin

Tags: spring-security, grails-spring-security, grails-3.3.x

#### Background:

In my project, I needed to have two factor authentication (by sending OTP to registered email) which I implemented by extending `DaoAuthenticationProvider`.

In order to identify reason of why OTP authentication has failed,  my custom authentication provider throws new custom exceptions for example  `BadOtpException`, `ExpiredOtpException`, `ConsumedOtpException`. All these exceptions are subclasses of `BadCredentialsException`. This authentication flow is working fine.

#### Issue:

The Authentication events that were earlier getting published while I was using `DaoAuthenticationProvider` are now not getting published with my custom authentication provider.

#### Cause:

Upon some troubleshooting I figured out that Grails Spring Security Core plugin uses `DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher` to publish the events. And this class publishes events on the basis of exception mappings which contain exception name vs event name to resolve the event that needs to be published whenever exception occurs. And these mappings  are configured in its constructor.
Since mappings of my custom exceptions are not present in this constructor, the authentication failure events are not getting published.

#### Tried Solution:

I tried overriding `DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher` and added new exception mappings by invoking `super.setAdditionalExceptionMappings()`. Here is the custom event publisher:

```
class CustomAuthenticationEventPublisher extends DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher {
CustomAuthenticationEventPublisher() {

}

CustomAuthenticationEventPublisher(ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher) {
    super(applicationEventPublisher)
    println('CustomAuthenticationEventPublisher')
    Properties exceptionMappings = new Properties()
    exceptionMappings.setProperty(BadOtpException.class.name, AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent.class.name)
    super.setAdditionalExceptionMappings(exceptionMappings)
}
}
```

In resources.groovy, I registered my custom event publisher using following:

```
beans = {
   authenticationEventPublisher(CustomAuthenticationEventPublisher)
}
```

But above solution is not working. Even the `println()` statement in the constructor is not getting logged. Seems like the bean is not getting registered.

Am I doing anything wrong in the above solution?

Is there any other way I can override the exception mappings?

Answer (score 0):

With bit of more troubleshooting, I realized that zero argument constructor of the class `CustomAuthenticationEventPublisher` was being called instead of the other one.

So I tried setting the exception mappings in constructor and it worked.
Here is the code that worked form me:

```
class CustomAuthenticationEventPublisher extends DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher {
   CustomAuthenticationEventPublisher() {
   println('CustomAuthenticationEventPublisher')
   Properties exceptionMappings = new Properties()
   exceptionMappings.setProperty(BadOtpException.class.name,  AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent.class.name)
     super.setAdditionalExceptionMappings(exceptionMappings)
 }

 CustomAuthenticationEventPublisher(ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher) {
     super(applicationEventPublisher)
   
 }
}
```

Thanks.